# Unit Testing Failing on Build Server

Tags: tfsbuild

We had a build server doing CI. All of a sudden the Unit test were failing without any changes. We are getting below error:

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.TestRunner.ProcessExitedException: Executor process exited. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.FinishSyncRead(Boolean traceExceptionsAsErrors)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.ITestExecutorService.InitializeConnection(IEnumerable`1 pathToAdditionalExtensions, Boolean loadOnlyWellKnownExtensions) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceProxy.InitializeConnection(IEnumerable`1 pathToAdditionalExtensions, Boolean loadOnlyWellKnownExtensions)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.TestConnection(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address, ITestExecutorServiceProxy& proxy)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.InitializeProxy(String namedPipeIdentifierToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.CheckExecutorProcessExited(Exception ex)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.InitializeProxy(String namedPipeIdentifierToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.Initialize_NoLock(Architecture targetPlatform, FrameworkVersion targetFramework)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.EnsureInitialized(IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestExecutionContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<StartTestRun>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.InvokeTestExecutorServiceAction(Action action) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestExecutorServiceClient.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1 sources, TestExecutionContext executionContext, String runSettings, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, String dataCollectionServiceUri, ITestCaseLog testCaseLog, ITestRunLog testRunLog, IFrameworkHandleInternal frameworkHandle) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.Rocksteady.ParallelTestExecutorServiceClient.TriggerExecutionForNextSource(ITestExecutorServiceClient executorServiceClient) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.Rocksteady.ParallelTestExecutorServiceClient.<StartTestRunPrivate>b__23_0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.Rocksteady.ParallelTestExecutorServiceClient.StartTestRunPrivate(TestExecutionContext executionContext, String runSettings, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, String dataCollectionServiceUri, ITestCaseLog testCaseLog, ITestRunLog testRunLog, IFrameworkHandleInternal frameworkHandle) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.Rocksteady.ParallelTestExecutorServiceClient.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1 sources, TestExecutionContext executionContext, String runSettings, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, String dataCollectionServiceUri, ITestCaseLog testCaseLog, ITestRunLog testRunLog, IFrameworkHandleInternal frameworkHandle) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.Rocksteady.RocksteadyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, Boolean inIsolation, DataCollectionParameters dataCollectionParameters, ITestRunEventsHandler runEventsHandler) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.RunTestsArgumentProcessor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, String packageFullName, String deviceInfo, Boolean isPhoneAppx, Boolean isUniversalTestAppx)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.RunTestsArgumentProcessor.Execute()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Executor.Execute(String[] args)
at RockSteady.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Check the method in  this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919703/wcf-error-there-was-an-error-reading-from-the-pipe-unrecognized-error-109-0x6 And you can share the pipeline definition. It will help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by updating visual studio license on the server